# Converting column values to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where all values in column `B` are the same. It looks like this:

```
        A               B
0  Marble Hill     Pizza Place
1  Chinatown       Pizza Place
2  Washington      Pizza Place
3  Washington      Pizza Place
4  Inwood          Pizza Place
5  Inwood          Pizza Place
```

I wish to convert column `A` values to rows. Then column `B` should count the number occurrences of each value from `A`.
I want it to look like this:

```
                B
Marble Hill     1   
Chinatown       1
Washington      2
Inwood          2
```

Comment: Can you show what code you've already written/tried?

Answer (score 2):

pandas's [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) does exactly that. It returns a series with the number of occurrences of each value.

`new_df = df["A"].value_counts()`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the way you are describing your data, it looks like you have a Pandas dataframe.
If that is the case then you can use the `value_counts` method on column `A` to get the result you want.
Assuming your dataframe is stored in the variable name `df`, then...

```
df['A'].value_counts()
```